# Brake DC MOTOR circuit

Tags: transistors, dc, pwm, dc-motor, npn

I have a DC motor that is controlled with an npn transistor with pwm. Everything works fine. I want to brake the motor instantly. I tried to short the terminals with another pairs of transistors but did't work.

[image]

Comment: Can you show a schematic of the circuit you used for braking?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgvDZ.gif

Comment: didn't work is not a good description. What *Did* it do? transistors blow up? Motor did slow down but not 'instantly'? Other? Edit the circuit into your question, comments can and do vanish.

Comment: That is the circuit.

Comment: Nothing happens when I short the terminals of the motor. Motor stops normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider the VCE(sat) of the transistor used to short the motor and it will not work as the speed slows.
The best is to use a P-channel FET to short the motor as it will conduct at much lower V(DS) voltages and is much closer to resistive braking. You should first measure the back-EMF you expect so you know what you are dealing with.

Read this excellent [application note](https://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/content/ab-021-measuring-rpm-from-back-emf/) from Precision on measuring your back-EMF for the motor.

Answer (score 1):

Braking by shorting depends on the Back-EMF generated by the motor itself. It only works at high speeds. At low speeds, the voltage is low, so is the short current and the braking torque.

If you need a really high braking torque at any speed, you had to reverse the external voltage, using a H-bridge – as for reversing the direction. Because that's what you had to do. And of course, a way to measure the speed so you can stop braking before you accelerate in the opposite direction.